# Clip a line inside a circle with Two.js using SVG

Tags: two.js

I want to draw a line that goes through a circle but is clipped by the boundary of the circle. Here is my code so far,

```
var elem = document.getElementById('draw-shapes');
var params = { width: 600, height: 400 };
var two = new Two(params).appendTo(elem);
var center = { x: params.width/2, y: params.height/2};
var circle = two.makeCircle(center.x, center.y, 80);
var line = two.makeLine(0, 0, 600, 300);

circle.fill = 'white';
circle.stroke = 'black';
circle.linewidth = 2;
// circle.clip = true;

line.stroke = 'black';
line.linewidth = 2;

line.mask = circle;

two.update();
```

I have tried to comment out and keep the `circle.clip = true` line but it only hides the circle itself when set to `true`. The line itself is drawn normally.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using [Two.js](https://two.js.org/). This is a [working example](https://jsbin.com/posacezobo/edit?html,output).

Comment: Show a picture of what you have and what you are trying to achieve.  Why not just make the line shorter based on the line width?

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb I have added a JS Bin example. Right now, the line goes through the circle. I want it to stop at the circumference as if it is a chord.

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb I don't always know how long the line will be and its exact co-ordinates on the circumeference.

Comment: In order to make it work I would remove some transforms - is this OK with you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with something like

```
var line = two.makeLine(center.x+circle.vertices[0].x, center.y+circle.vertices[0].y, center.x+circle.vertices[5].x, center.y+circle.vertices[5].y);
```

[image: output]

**Update:**

The vertices are drawn based on the resolution chosen

```
makeCircle: function(x, y, radius, resolution) {

    var circle = new Circle(x, y, radius, resolution);
    this.scene.add(circle);

    return circle;

  }
```

and

```
/**
 * @name Two.Circle
 * @class
 * @extends Two.Path
 * @param {Number} [x=0] - The x position of the circle.
 * @param {Number} [y=0] - The y position of the circle.
 * @param {Number} radius - The radius value of the circle.
 * @param {Number} [resolution=4] - The number of vertices used to construct the circle.
 */
var Circle = function(ox, oy, r, resolution) {

  // At least 2 vertices are required for proper circlage
  var amount = resolution ? Math.max(resolution, 2) : 4;

  var points = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    points.push(new Anchor());
  }

  Path.call(this, points, true, true, true);

  /**
   * @name Two.Circle#radius
   * @property {Number} - The size of the radius of the circle.
   */
  this.radius = r;

  this._update();

  if (typeof ox === 'number') {
    this.translation.x = ox;
  }
  if (typeof oy === 'number') {
    this.translation.y = oy;
  }

};
```

and

```
_update: function() {

    if (this._flagRadius) {
      // Coefficient for approximating circular arcs with Bezier curves
      var c = (4 / 3) * Math.tan(Math.PI / (this.vertices.length * 2));

      var radius = this._radius;
      var rc = radius * c;

      for (var i = 0, numVertices = this.vertices.length; i < numVertices; i++) {
        var pct = i / numVertices;
        var theta = pct * TWO_PI;

        var x = radius * cos(theta);
        var y = radius * sin(theta);

        var lx = rc * cos(theta - HALF_PI);
        var ly = rc * sin(theta - HALF_PI);

        var rx = rc * cos(theta + HALF_PI);
        var ry = rc * sin(theta + HALF_PI);

        var v = this.vertices[i];

        v.command = Commands.curve;
        v.set(x, y);
        v.controls.left.set(lx, ly);
        v.controls.right.set(rx, ry);
      }
    }

    Path.prototype._update.call(this);
    return this;

  }
```

https://github.com/jonobr1/two.js/blob/dev/src/shapes/circle.js#L23

You can use the library or mathematically calculate the points

Comment: Thanks @Hitham :) But where did these vertices `circle.vertices[5]` come from?